# Writing an IF statement

Tags: php

I need an if statement on this to only create the wrapping anchor link if getBlockLink exists. Failed with all attempts so far. Can any php wizards out there supply me with a solution?

```
<div class="<?php echo $this->getSize(); ?>">
<a href="<?php echo $this->getBlockLink(); ?>">
    <span class="grid grid--full">
        <span class="grid__item <?php echo $this->getTextPosition() . ' ' .  $this->getTextWidth(); ?>">
            <?php echo $this->getBlockFormattedContent(); ?>
        </span>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getImage(); ?>">
    </span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Need a real question other than give me an if. Check the examples on http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<div class="<?php echo $this->getSize(); ?>">
  <?php if (!empty($this->getBlockLink())) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBlockLink(); ?>">
  <?php endif; ?>
  <span class="grid grid--full">
    <span class="grid__item <?php echo $this->getTextPosition() . ' ' .  $this->getTextWidth(); ?>">
      <?php echo $this->getBlockFormattedContent(); ?>
    </span>
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getImage(); ?>">
  </span>
  <?php if (!empty($this->getBlockLink())) : ?>
    </a>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This seems to work

```
<div class="<?php echo $this->getSize(); ?>">
<?php if($this->getBlockLink()): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBlockLink(); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
    <span class="grid grid--full">
        <span class="block_content grid__item <?php echo $this->getTextPosition() . ' ' .  $this->getTextWidth(); ?>">
            <?php echo $this->getBlockFormattedContent(); ?>
        </span>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getImage(); ?>">
    </span>
<?php if($this->getBlockLink()): ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```